# EventType is not a class or namespace

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

I'm trying to make a simple 2D game using SFML and [this](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/page/Game-From-Scratch-CPP-Edition-Part-3.aspx) tutorial. Here's to code for my current progress in the tutorial: I'm having problem with the enum EventType for class Event. Member variable name is Type.

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include "SplashScreen.h"


 void SplashScreen::Show(sf::RenderWindow & renderWindow)
 {
    sf::Image image;
    if(image.LoadFromFile("images/SplashScreen.png") != true)
    {
     return;
    }

   sf::Sprite sprite(image);

   renderWindow.Draw(sprite);
   renderWindow.Display();

   sf::Event event;
   while(true)
   {
     while(renderWindow.GetEvent(event))
     {
       if( event.Type == sf::Event::EventType::KeyPressed
         || event.Type == sf::Event::EventType::MouseButtonPressed
         || event.Type == sf::Event::EventType::Closed )
       {
          return;
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

This is my stdafx.h:

```
 // stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
 // or project specific include files that are used frequently, but
 // are changed infrequently
 //

 #ifndef STDAFX_H
 #define STDAFX_H


 #include <stdio.h>


 // TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here
 #include <SFML/System.hpp>
 #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
 #include <SFML/Window.hpp>
 #include <SFML/Audio.hpp>

 #include <map>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cassert>

 #endif //STDAFX_H
```

It seems it has included Event.hpp because I've autocompletation works for event. MouseButtonPressed and all the other enum values appears after `sf::Event::EventType::` scope in Code Blocks. I've also checked Event.hpp file and it is correct. I don't understand why the compiler is messing with me.

When i try to remove the scopes and only write "event.Type == KeyPressed" instead the compiler says "Keypressed was not declared in this scope". 
I run Code Blocks 10.05 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Know what's wrong?

Edit: [This](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6/Event_8hpp_source.php) is my Event.hpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the enum is not a scope. Just replace `sf::Event::EventType::KeyPressed` to `sf::Event::KeyPressed`.

Answer (score 0):

collegue, way you don't include the SF.h directaly ? Like this:

## include

////// and use the namespace: using namespace sf;

//// avoiding use sf:: before whole sentence=>  //// sf::Event....

while(window.isOpen())
{ //.`enter code here`..

```
Event event
while(window.pollEvent(event)
{`enter code here`
if(event.type == Event::KeyPressed)
  if(event.key.code == Keyboard::Up)
  `enter code here`
```